# Setting scope variable in controller is undefined

Tags: angularjs

If i set a scope variable like this it works just fine:

```
$scope.event = new Date();
```

but if i set this, i get an undefined error:

```
$scope.event.start.time = new Date();
```

Why and how can I set `$scope.event.start.time`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With something like this:

```
$scope.event = {
  start: {
    time: new Date()
  }
};
```

Otherwise, as JS doesn't have auto-vivification, you'll attempt to access (set) a property of `undefined`.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. I got spoiled with just making up variables in the view.